# Recommendations for books with solutions, to review wholly high school math?

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for books for the full high school maths curriculum, just to refresh myself (it's been years). it must have questions & solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you posted this question earlier today and I had about a three paragraph response with a ton of advice but then you deleted the post (apologies if that wasn't you). So... here is the abbreviated version. Read the following books,

- Practice Makes Perfect: Algebra. [[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071638199)]
- Practice Makes Perfect: Precalculus. [[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071761780)]
- Practice Makes Perfect: Calculus. [[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071638156)]

If you are interested in getting access to higher mathematics afterwards I recommend the following book by Chartrand, Polimeni, and Zhang. It is an incredible introduction to proofs and various areas of mathematics.

"Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics" by Gary Chartrand, Albert D. Polimeni, and Ping Zhang. [[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321390539)]

There is an entire chapter devoted to each of the following:

- Communicating Mathematics
- Naive Set Theory
- Logic
- Direct Proof
- Proof by Contrapositive
- Existence and Proof by Contradiction
- Mathematical Induction (and Strong Induction)
- Equivalence Relations (Equivalence Classes, Congruence Modulo n, Modular arithmetic)
- Functions (Bijective, Inverse, Permutations)
- Set Theory (up to Schroder-Bernstein Theorem and the Continuum Hypothesis)
- Number Theory
- Calculus (Limits, Infinite Series, Continuity, Differentiability)
- Group Theory (up to Isomorphic Groups)

With [Three Additional Chapters](http://www.aw-bc.com/chartrand/) online covering:

- Ring Theory
- Linear Algebra
- Topology

That should keep you busy for a while, and after reading through Chartrand/Polimeni/Zhang, you will know what area of mathematics you are more interested in or if you still want to learn more!

Comment: No problem! Hopefully you actually get through this material. I really encourage you to try and do it. If you have any conceptual troubles or questions about a specific exercise remember that you can always ask for help this site!

Comment: It should be fine, I used to be an "ace", but its just been sooooo long, planning to get a mathematical degree and dont want to look like a complete fool :) heheh