# Complete undergraduate bundle-pack

Tags: reference-request, education

First of all I'm sorry if this is not the right place to post this. I like math a lot. But I'm not sure if i want to do a math major in college. My question is: Can you give me a list of books that will give me the knowledge of the subjects a person doing a math major would have? I think I know all the stuff a good high school student knows. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking. Do you want resources which will give you an idea of what you'd learn as a math undergrad?

Comment: I think this is just too broad, but we'll see what others have to say. Here's an idea: go to the math department webpage for a university — e.g., [Northwestern](http://math.northwestern.edu/) or [Michigan](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/) — and see which courses they require of undergraduates. Find webpages for those courses and see what sorts of books and assignments they use. You don't really need an expert for any of this.

Comment: A good math major and a good mathematician has knowledge of subjects other math majors do not have.

Comment: Or, if you want to do it right, you could check the [University of Chicago](http://math.uchicago.edu/).

Comment: Speaking of that school to the south, there is [this annotated list of books](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm).

Comment: @DylanMoreland I had no idea Pete Clark went to Chicago!

Comment: @Alex: What, were you expecting a shrine in my name in Eckhart Hall?  Hmm, well you could at least *ask* Diane Herrmann about it...

Comment: Some universities put all/most of their notes online. For example, MIT's [OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/). So, perhaps that is a good place to start? (It is free-er than buying books! But I do prefer reading books to looking at a computer screen...)

Comment: This blog posts has some interesting list of topics and books/online materials for them: [How to Become a Pure Mathematician](http://hbpms.blogspot.com/).

Comment: Actually I have a very different answer because I don't think it is necessary or even good to just cover as much 'relevant' content as possible. Rather from my experience with others, once you are able to devise proofs on your own that are both complete and precise, and understand exactly how a proof utilizes the structure of the objects involved, then the content itself will be easy to pick up naturally along the way. For this I would suggest that you start with a book like Spivak's Calculus and attempt to prove each theorem yourself before reading the given proof, and not just do exercises.

Comment: **Duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127814**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using some of the recommendations Others gave me and the Stanford math major checklist I have made the following list: One should read all books corresponding to a subject (in order) not just one of them.. The first part is a requirement while in the second part students usually take at least 2 electives ( I give 4 examples).

*Calculus*:

Calculus by Michael Spivak

Calculus volumes 1 and 2 by Tom M.Apostol

*Analysis*

Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin

Real and complex analysis by Walter Rudin

*Topology*

Topology by James Munkres or

General Topology by Stephen Willard (harder)

*Linear Algebra*

Linear Algebra by Friedberg,Insel and Spence

Differential Equations:

*Ordinary Differential Equations* by Tenenbaum and Polland

*Partial Differential equations* by Lawrence C evans.

*Algebra*

*Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote

Combinatorics

*Introductory Combinatorics* by Brualdi

Set theory:

*Introduction to set theory* by Hrbacek and Jech

**Electives:**

Algebraic Topology

Algebraic Topology: an introduction by W.S Massey

Algebraic Geometry

Undergraduate algebraic geometry by Miles Reid

Number theory:

An introduction to the theory of numbers by Hardy and Wright

Algebraic number Theory (If you also take Number theory)

Algebraic Theory of numbers by Pierre Samuel.

Comment: Im going to try to read all of these books in the following three years and ill let you know how it works out for me.

Comment: You would be lucky to read all of them in next three years.

Comment: +1. Excellent list except for "big Rudin" included-that's way too tough for most undergraduates. I'd also recommend Vinberg's A COURSE IN ALGEBRA instead of Dummit/Foote.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling How did the reading work out for you?

Comment: I read everything except for differential equations, those suck. Although I'm more into computer science now.

Comment: im almost done with my undergraduate studies now. I think this list would do well with a functional analysis book. Also, set theory is optional in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one possible list.

*Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin

*Topology* by James Munkres

*Linear Algebra* by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence

*Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote

Comment: Some do; I personally didn't (not the OP). If you'd like a combinatorics book though, I recommend Introductory Combinatorics by Brualdi. Lots of information with good exposition and examples.

Comment: Ah. A doable list. Not only that, but if you do only these books but thoroughly, then you will actually be more than well prepared for most grad programs.

Answer (score 7):

This is a blog which describes on [how to be a pure mathematician](http://hbpms.blogspot.in/). You can go through it and find out what all opportunities you have in various fields of mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another useful list.

This is a link to the Mathematics Programs offered at the University of Toronto (St. George):

http://www.artsandscience.utoronto.ca/ofr/archived/1213calendar/crs_mat.htm

A course number with a Y indicates a full year course (72 hrs of lecture) and a course number with H indicates a half year course (36 hrs of lecture):

**First Year**

**MAT157Y1 - Analysis I**
Text: Calculus by Spivak. 
Used in the past: Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin.

If you have never been exposed to abstract mathematics Spivak is probably better to go with. UofT has been teaching from Spivak's for awhile now.

**MAT240H1 & Mat247H1: Linear Algebra I & II**
Text: Linear Algebra by Friedberg et al.
Used in the past: Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler.

**Second Year**

**MAT257Y1 - Analysis II**

Text - Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres
Used in th past: Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak

Go with Munkres on this one. Spivak is barely a little over 100 pages in length! So you can imagine how terse it is.

**MAT267H1 - Advanced Ordinary Differential Equations**
Text - Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, & Introduction to Chaos by Hirsch et al. & Elementary Differential Equations by Boyce and DiPrima

**Third Year**

**MAT347Y1 - Groups, Rings, & Fields**
Text: Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote

**MAT354H1 - Complex Analysis I**
Text: Complex Analysis by Stein & Shakarchi. 
Used in the past: Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin

**MAT315H1 - Introduction to Number Theory**
Text: An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Niven.
Used in the past: A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory by Silverman.

**MAT344H1 - Introduction to Combinatorics**
Text: Applied Combinatorics by Tucker

**MAT327H1 - Introduction to Topology**
Text: Topology by Munkres.

**MAT357H1 - Real Analysis I**
Text: Real Mathematical Analysis by Pugh. 
Used in the past: Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin.

**MAT363H1 - Introduction to Differential Geometry**
Text: Elementary Differential Geometry by Pressley.

**Fourth Year**

A lot of these courses are cross listed so they're actually graduate courses. Check here for texts and references:

http://www.math.toronto.edu/cms/tentative-2012-2013-graduate-courses-descriptions/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

### Chicago undergraduate mathematics bibliography

---

> ### ELEMENTARY
>
> This includes “high school topics” and first-year calculus. Contents

- **Algebra** $(4)$

  - [*Gelfand/Shen*, Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817636773)
  - [*Gelfand/Glagoleva/Shnol*, Functions and graphs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486425649)
  - [*Gelfand/Glagoleva/Kirillov*, The method of coordinates](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486425657)
  - [*Cohen*, Precalculus with unit circle trigonometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534402305), and its content is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606807/93957).
- **Geometry** $(2)$

  - [*Euclid*, The elements](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1888009195)
  - [*Coxeter,* Geometry revisited](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856190)
- **Foundations** $(1)$

  - [*Rucker,* Infinity and the mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691121273)
- **Problem solving** $(4)$

  - New Mathematical Library problem books
  - [*Larson,* Problem solving through problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961712)
  - [*Pólya,* How to solve it](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/069111966X)
  - [*Pólya,* Mathematics and plausible reasoning, I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691025096) [and II](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/069102510X)
- **Calculus** $(6)$

  - [*Spivak,* Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098918)
  - [*Spivak,* The hitchhiker's guide to calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883858126)
  - [*Hardy,* A course of pure mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1603860495)
  - [*Courant,* Differential and integral calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471588814)
  - [*Apostol,* Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471000051)
  - [*Janusz,* Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Calculus-Gerald-J-Janusz/dp/0697153746)
- **Bridges to intermediate topics** $(2) $

  - [*Smith,* Introduction to mathematics: algebra and analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introductory-Mathematics-Analysis-Springer-Undergraduate/dp/3540761780/ref=tmm_pap_title_0)
  - [*Johnson,* Introduction to logic via numbers and sets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540761233)

---

> ### INTERMEDIATE
>
> Roughly, general rather than specialized texts in higher mathematics. I would not hesitate to recommend any book here to honors second-years, but they might not find easy going in some of them.

- Foundations $(5)$

  - [*Halmos,* Naive set theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271313)
  - [*Fraenkel,* Abstract set theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WT6T4U)
  - [*Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas,* Mathematical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387942580)
  - [*Enderton,* A mathematical introduction to logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520)
  - [*Landau,* Foundations of analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082182693X)
- General abstract algebra $(7)$ (difficulty: $\color{orange}{\mathscr{m}}$oderate-$\color{red}{\mathscr{h}}$igher)

  - $\color{orange}{\mathscr{m}}$ - [*Dummit/Foote,* Abstract algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433349)
  - $\color{orange}{\mathscr{m}}$ - [*Herstein,* Topics in algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471010901)
  - $\color{orange}{\mathscr{m}}$ - [*Artin,* Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130047635)
  - $\color{red}{\mathscr{h}}$ - [*Jacobson,* Basic algebra I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486471896)
  - $\color{red}{\mathscr{h}}$ - [*Hungerford,* Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387905189)
  - $\color{red}{\mathscr{h}}$ - [*Lang,* Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038795385X)
  - $\color{red}{\mathscr{h}}$ - [*Mac Lane/Birkhoff,* Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821816462)
- Linear algebra $(3)$

  - [*Halmos,* Finite dimensional vector spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1258812584)
  - [*Curtis,* Abstract linear algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387972633)
  - [*Greub,* Linear algebra and Multilinear algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387901108)
- Number theory $(5)$

  - [*Ireland/Rosen,* A classical introduction to modern number theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038797329X)
  - [*Burn,* A pathway into number theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521575400)

    ### - [*Hardy/Wright,* Introduction to number theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198531710)
    -
- ### Combinatorics and discrete mathematics $(1)$
- ### Real analysis $(10)$

  ### -

  ### -

  ### -

  ### -

    -
- ### Multivariable calculus $(2)$

    -
- ### Complex analysis $(5)$

  ### -

  ### -
- ### Differential equations $(2)$

    -
- ### Point-set topology $(5)$

  ### -

  ### -
- ### Differential geometry $(4)$

  ### -

    -
- ### Classical geometry $(3) $

  ### -

---

TO BE CONTINUED

Comment: Nice! I wish you'd finish this off though..

Comment: @seeker The reference is here https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm

Comment: @danu I know, but I'd love to print this, it's nicely formatted and everything

Comment: User, do you intend to finish this? I would be interested. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure about this question, and its intent. But it is always important to have an idea of some ways to continue one's education.

One of my favorite, though undermentioned, resources is the Mathematics Autodidact's Guide, published by the AMS. It's a short pdf (linked [here](http://www.ams.org/notices/200510/comm-fowler.pdf)).

But FWIW, here is a list of the undergraduate math classes and their books I took and used, respectively, as an undergrad (this doesn't account for my self-study or the research bits that I did, but every budding mathematician must distinguish himself from the rest in some way or another):

Calculus (3 semesters):
Calculus in One and Several Variables by Salas, Hille, and Etgen
Vector Calculus by Marsden

Linear Algebra (2 semesters):
Carlen and Carvalho's terrible, terrible book
Linear Algebra by Apostol
Topics in Algebra by Herstein

Algebra (3 semesters):
Topics in Algebra by Herstein
Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote

Real Analysis (2 semesters):
Intro to Real Analysis by Rosenlicht (great, though few know it)
Real Analysis by Bartle (this is intense, but flawed in that it doesn't do Lebesgue)
Advanced Calculus of Several Variables by Edwards (this was done with Bartle in one semester)

DE (2 semesters):
One of the Ordinary Differential Equations by Marsden (boring)
Calculus of Variations by Gelfand and Fomin

Probability (1 semester, thank god):
Intro to Probability by Hogg and Tanis

Combinatorics (1 semester):
Discrete Mathematics by Grimaldi

Graph Theory (1 semester):
Graph Theory by West (a great book)

Number Theory (2 semesters):
Elementary Number Theory by Rosen (doesn't require algebra)
Introduction to Modern Number Theory by Ireland and Rosen (different Rosen, famous book)
Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory

Complex Analysis (2 semesters):
Stein and Shakarchi's Complex book (part of their series on analysis)
Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable

And then there were some electives in problem solving (using, e.g. Larson's Problem-Solving through Problems), game theory (Conway and Berlekamp's Winning Ways with your Mathematical Plays), additive number theory, etc. Find what interests you and follow it, I suppose.

Comment: Oh - I should note that there is a fundamental flaw in my undergraduate education: I never took a dedicated topology class. It wasn't until I went to grad school that I learned topology 'for real.'

Comment: @Chuck: I said exactly one of those books was terrible. Every book has strengths and weaknesses. Except for Carlen and Carvalho, which has only weaknesses.