# Recommend me math textbooks from prealgebra to undergrad level.

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, learning

So I've been reading through math.stack exchange and physics forums and r/learn math to find a comprehensive list of math textbooks to learn math from the ground up. I'm more wanting to do so to reinforce and patch up my foundations or I guess just entirely rebuild them.

Yes, I have found some lists but nothing seems to cover prealgebra books as well that aren't just for little kids. And yes I do know about Khan Academy but I would like to own some physical books. I'm also not trying to make this too personal as to make it useful to other people.

So please recommend me mathematic textbooks from prealgebra upwards, basically as far as your experience, understanding and knowledge permits.

Thank you for your time and any recommendations you can make.

Edit: So this was flagged as being a duplicate post. I want to hopefully point out how it is not like the post that was linked.

Basically I'm looking for recommendations on math textbooks from pre-algebra upwards not just a book/s for pre-calculus. So a comprehensive list of books starting at pre-algebra then algebra then geometry, then trigonometry then pre-calculus, then calculus and beyond calculus as well as all the sections I missed in-between.

anyway hopefully you can help, thank you.

Comment: You may wish to look at the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174876/complete-undergraduate-bundle-pack

Comment: Since the cited questions appear to omit anything below precalculus (indeed, some of the suggestions in the precalculus question you cited mention books several years beyond the level of precalculus), here are some suggestions: Issac Asimov's [**Realm of Numbers**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0395065666) and [**Realm of Algebra**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0449243982) (for armchair reading; in the U.S. these can often be found at public libraries); The Art of Problem Solving's [**Prealgebra**](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/viewitem.php?item=prealgebra) text (for hands-on studying).

Comment: **(continuation)** For algebra, the Mary P. Dolciani texts [**Algebra 1**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0395430569) and [**Algebra 2**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0395470560) are hard to beat (these can often found in U.S. public libraries). For geometry, Harold R. Jacobs' book [**Geometry: Seeing, Doing, Understanding**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0716743612) looks good, but I have not personally seen it. Finally, for precalculus I recommend Sheldon Axler's [**Precalculus**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0470416742).