# getting started self study

Tags: soft-question, advice, learning

I am 14 and currently in year 10 (uk). I am very interested in maths and intend to pursue it. I currently can do C1, C2, C3 and parts of C4 edexcel exam board a level mathematics. However, when i learn something new i have trouble truly remembering it and this is the same for the a level maths i have done. I have used a variety of resources up to now including khan academy, mit open courseware for calculus and quite a few more including the edexcel textbooks which i find awkward to use. I would appreciate a suggested order to learn each topic from beginning a levels to end of bachelors degree and also i would appreciate good resources or books to use. The reason i wish for resources to a level basics is because i would like to relearn it so ensure it is safe in my mind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following link might be of interest to you. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/761/undergraduate-level-math-books

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I self-learn undergraduate math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127814/how-do-i-self-learn-undergraduate-math)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you the book I liked very much when I was your age:

"What is mathematics?"

by R. Courant and H. Robbins.

If I may give you one advice: do not concentrate on remembering math. Concentrate on understanding it. Some people claim that very good memory is rather a handicap in mathematics (a little joke, but I find something true in this statement:)

Comment: my apologies that is what i meant buy remembering and that book looks great thanks.

Comment: i have not been able to get this from what i have read but, does this book teach you the maths or does it just teach you about the maths if i am making any sense?

Comment: It does both things. While it is not a typical textbook, by studying it you can familiarize yourself with mathematical concepts that are used through whole mathematics. It has some exercises also.

Comment: it looks great thank. I am looking at the google books preview and i cant quite see but does it include topics other than algebra and geometry etc. at "a level" level such as trigonometry and calculus.

Comment: This book presents some of the core ideas of mathematics. While the presentation is on quite elementary level the ideas presented are deep. If I remember correctly it starts with natural numbers and induction, then shows constructions of other number system, complex numbers included, it goes through algebraic proofs of impossibility of classical geometric constructions, discusses various other geometries (projective geometry etc), treats basic calculus in quite a detail (but with all intuitions) and goes to topology. Treat this book as a bridge to higher mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Do more homework problems.  Periodically retest yourself.  When you see a weakness, hit it with more problems.