# Book to prepare for university math?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Can you suggest some books to prepare for university math?

Comment: what do you mean by "University math" ?

Comment: Check out William Chen's lecture notes for [first year mathematics](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnmtfymfolder/lnmtfym.html) and the ones with X.T. Duong on [elementary mathematics](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnemfolder/lnem.html). Check out the syllabi for the courses you'll be taking, see if they have online materials available. Peek into their textbooks (e.g. via [Google Books](http://books.google.com)).

Comment: [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521446635), by [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/)

Comment: Nick's great answer has a number of "how to do university maths" style books, I would also suggest trying to find the book list for the most introductory courses at a university you are going to (or hope to) study and take a look at those. After all many university students don't do any extra prereading and get along fine with them (of course they have lectures and other classes to help so you should expect to find it harder at first, but you will definitely be better off for having done it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a broad question. However, I will try to list (in no particular order) a few books that may be useful in the transition from high school to university maths:

[1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321797094)Gary Chartrand, Albert D. Polimeni and Ping Zhang, [Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics, Third Edition.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321797094)

> Appropriate for self-study or for use in the classroom, this text
>   introduces students to proof techniques, analyzing proofs, and writing
>   proofs of their own. Written in a clear, conversational style, this
>   book provides a solid introduction to such topics as relations,
>   functions, and cardinalities of sets, as well as the theoretical
>   aspects of fields such as number theory, abstract algebra, and group
>   theory. It is also a great reference text that students can look back
>   to when writing or reading proofs in their more advanced courses.

[2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052171978X)Kevin Houston, [How to Think Like a Mathematician: A Companion to Undergraduate Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052171978X)

> Looking for a head start in your undergraduate degree in mathematics?
>   Maybe you've already started your degree and feel bewildered by the
>   subject you previously loved? Don't panic! This friendly companion
>   will ease your transition to real mathematical thinking. Working
>   through the book you will develop an arsenal of techniques to help you
>   unlock the meaning of definitions, theorems and proofs, solve
>   problems, and write mathematics effectively. All the major methods of
>   proof - direct method, cases, induction, contradiction and
>   contrapositive - are featured. Concrete examples are used throughout,
>   and you'll get plenty of practice on topics common to many courses
>   such as divisors, Euclidean algorithms, modular arithmetic,
>   equivalence relations, and injectivity and surjectivity of functions.
>   The material has been tested by real students over many years so all
>   the essentials are covered. With over 300 exercises to help you test
>   your progress, you'll soon learn how to think like a mathematician.

[3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615653634)Keith Devlin, [Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615653634)

> In the twenty-first century, everyone can benefit from being able to
>   think mathematically. This is not the same as “doing math.” The latter
>   usually involves the application of formulas, procedures, and symbolic
>   manipulations; mathematical thinking is a powerful way of thinking
>   about things in the world -- logically, analytically, quantitatively,
>   and with precision. It is not a natural way of thinking, but it can be
>   learned. Mathematicians, scientists, and engineers need to “do math,”
>   and it takes many years of college-level education to learn all that
>   is required. Mathematical thinking is valuable to everyone, and can be
>   mastered in about six weeks by anyone who has completed high school
>   mathematics. Mathematical thinking does not have to be about
>   mathematics at all, but parts of mathematics provide the ideal target
>   domain to learn how to think that way, and that is the approach taken
>   by this short but valuable book. The book is written primarily for
>   first and second year students of science, technology, engineering,
>   and mathematics (STEM) at colleges and universities, and for high
>   school students intending to study a STEM subject at university. Many
>   students encounter difficulty going from high school math to
>   college-level mathematics. Even if they did well at math in school,
>   most are knocked off course for a while by the shift in emphasis, from
>   the K-12 focus on mastering procedures to the “mathematical thinking”
>   characteristic of much university mathematics. Though the majority
>   survive the transition, many do not. To help them make the shift,
>   colleges and universities often have a “transition course.” This book
>   could serve as a textbook or a supplementary source for such a course.
>   Because of the widespread applicability of mathematical thinking,
>   however, the book has been kept short and written in an engaging
>   style, to make it accessible to anyone who seeks to extend and improve
>   their analytic thinking skills. Going beyond a basic grasp of analytic
>   thinking that everyone can benefit from, the STEM student who truly
>   masters mathematical thinking will find that college-level mathematics
>   goes from being confusing, frustrating, and at times seemingly
>   impossible, to making sense and being hard but doable. Dr. Keith
>   Devlin is a professional mathematician at Stanford University and the
>   author of 31 previous books and over 80 research papers. His books
>   have earned him many awards, including the Pythagoras Prize, the Carl
>   Sagan Award, and the Joint Policy Board for Mathematics Communications
>   Award. He is known to millions of NPR listeners as “the Math Guy” on
>   Weekend Edition with Scott Simon. He writes a popular monthly blog
>   “Devlin’s Angle” for the Mathematical Association of America, another
>   blog under the name “profkeithdevlin”, and also blogs on various
>   topics for the Huffington Post.

[4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995)Daniel J. Velleman, [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995)

> Geared to preparing students to make the transition from solving
>   problems to proving theorems, this text teaches them the techniques
>   needed to read and write proofs. The book begins with the basic
>   concepts of logic and set theory, to familiarize students with the
>   language of mathematics and how it is interpreted. These concepts are
>   used as the basis for a step-by-step breakdown of the most important
>   techniques used in constructing proofs. To help students construct
>   their own proofs, this new edition contains over 200 new exercises,
>   selected solutions, and an introduction to Proof Designer software. No
>   background beyond standard high school mathematics is assumed.

[5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199661316)Lara Alcock, [How to Study as a Mathematics Major](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199661316)

> Every year, thousands of students declare mathematics as their major.
>   Many are extremely intelligent and hardworking. However, even the best
>   will encounter challenges, because upper-level mathematics involves
>   not only independent study and learning from lectures, but also a
>   fundamental shift from calculation to proof.
>
> This shift is demanding but it need not be mysterious -- research has
>   revealed many insights into the mathematical thinking required, and
>   this book translates these into practical advice for a student
>   audience. It covers every aspect of studying as a mathematics major,
>   from tackling abstract intellectual challenges to interacting with
>   professors and making good use of study time. Part 1 discusses the
>   nature of upper-level mathematics, and explains how students can adapt
>   and extend their existing skills in order to develop good
>   understanding. Part 2 covers study skills as these relate to
>   mathematics, and suggests practical approaches to learning effectively
>   while enjoying undergraduate life.
>
> As the first mathematics-specific study guide, this friendly,
>   practical text is essential reading for any mathematics major.

[6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199661324)Lara Alcock, [How to Study for a Mathematics Degree](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199661324)

> Every year, thousands of students go to university to study
>   mathematics (single honours or combined with another subject). Many of
>   these students are extremely intelligent and hardworking, but even the
>   best will, at some point, struggle with the demands of making the
>   transition to advanced mathematics. Some have difficulty adjusting to
>   independent study and to learning from lectures. Other struggles,
>   however, are more fundamental: the mathematics shifts in focus from
>   calculation to  proof, so students are expected to interact with it in
>   different ways. These changes need not be mysterious - mathematics
>   education research has revealed many insights into the adjustments
>   that are necessary - but they are not obvious and they do need
>   explaining.
>
> This no-nonsense book translates these research-based insights into
>   practical advice for a student audience. It covers every aspect of
>   studying for a mathematics degree, from the most abstract intellectual
>   challenges to the everyday business of interacting with lecturers and
>   making good use of study time. Part 1 provides an in-depth discussion
>   of advanced mathematical thinking, and explains how a student will
>   need to adapt and extend their existing skills in order to develop a
>   good  understanding of undergraduate mathematics. Part 2 covers study
>   skills as these relate to the demands of a mathematics degree. It
>   suggests practical approaches to learning from lectures and to
>   studying for examinations while also allowing time for a fulfilling
>   all-round university experience.
>
> The first subject-specific guide for students, this friendly,
>   practical text will be essential reading for anyone studying
>   mathematics at university.

In addition, you might want to have a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127814/preparing-for-university-and-advanced-mathematics).

Good luck with your studies (although a successful mathematician needs to be hard working, dedicated, disciplined and PASSIONATE rather than merely "lucky")!

Comment: Check out [phdcomics](http://phdcomics.com) regularly. Don't forget [XKCD](http://xkcd.org).