# Self-study mathematics subject sequence and recommended books

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am a Physics student but I finally found that I've entered the wrong department that I am in fact much more interested in mathematics. I want to self-learn mathematics.

I am now reading Artin (Algebra) and Rudin (Prinicple of Mathematically Analysis). Both books are terrific.

Could anyone suggest a study sequence of subjects after that and some classic textbooks in each subject?

I am more interested in pure (I don't mind they being abstract) mathematics (especially those can be applied in quantum information theory, QFT, GR, quantum gravity, String theory, etc.).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this post may help you http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1447558/317580 and if you really find that post helpful then kindly flag it to remove it from hold. Also let me know if it helped you by leaving a comment here.

Comment: It is often advised to read several books simultaneously, as they can be complementary (as lectures are). I do not particularly know the english literature, but in general, if you are familiar with mathematical proofs (I mean, the way mathematics is done at university), I'd recommend to learn analysis jointly with topology and linear algebra. It is good to learn some statistics and probability but not too deeply since they require measure theory (taught in advanced analysis, in general).
These are a basis, of course; there are plenty of subjects.

Comment: @user109256 No, that post doesn't help me a lot. Please please don't delete my post here.

Comment: @Mathaholic What made you think that I'll delete you post?

Comment: Duplicates will be removed, aren't they?

Comment: @Mathaholic I don't think it's a duplicate but I just redirected you to that post because I thought that may be helpful to you.

Comment: @user109256 OK. Thanks!

Comment: I am personally of the opinion that anyone who calls Rudin "terrific" is either a masochist or overly charitable, but all the power to you!  You might want to look into [Munkres' Topology](http://www.amazon.com/Topology-2nd-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292) as a next step.

Comment: If you're particularly interested in the things that tie into quantum information theory, you should also look into functional analysis! I recommend either [Kreyszig](http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Functional-Analysis-Applications-Kreyszig/dp/0471504599) (because it's readable) or [Pedersen's Analysis Now](http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Now-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387967885) (because it gets to the point).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom +1 for the recommendation. I have followed both of them on similar lines.

Comment: If you're more of an algebraist than an analyst (that is, if you prefer homomorphisms to epsilons and deltas), you might also want to consider looking into algebraic geometry. [An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-4497-2) is good for a first look, [Hartshorne](http://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Geometry-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387902449) is good if you're looking for a real project.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for the recommendations!

Comment: Finally, if you feel like you want a good mix of linear algebra and abstract algebra, you should consider looking into either "representation theory" or "Lie Groups and Lie Algebras".  I don't think I have helpful recommendations for references on those subjects, though.

Comment: You're welcome!  Hope you enjoy it, whichever way you go.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I request you to convert those comments as an answer providing a few more similar details. It'll be helpful to other users seeking answers to similar questions.

Comment: @Mathaholic May you please briefly explain why Artin (Algebra) and Rudin (Prinicple of Mathematically Analysis) are terrific? I once considered to use those books for self-learning purposes.

Comment: @McCheng Very systematic, proofs are very rigorous and yet detailed and not difficult to follow, plenty of examples etc. I have no much background in rigorous mathematics (I am a physics student and you know the way physicists apply mathematics) can follow with no much difficulties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I self-learn undergraduate math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127814/how-do-i-self-learn-undergraduate-math)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of possible topics to look into after surviving Rudin:

- Topology ([Munkres](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292) is one of the canonical undergrad texts here).  In a nutshell: "what can we say about *closeness* without a direct notion of distance (i.e. a metric)? What can we say about *'continuous functions'?*"
- Functional analysis, to be taken *after* some topology ([Kreyszig](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504599) and [Pedersen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387967885) are my go-tos here).  This topic is key to understanding quantum information theory.  In a nutshell: linear algebra, but on infinite-dimensional vector-spaces.  Note: infinity is *weird*.
- Algebraic geometry ([reference 1](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-4497-2), [reference 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902449))
- Representation theory
- Lie Groups/Lie Algebras, together with some differential geometry.

(See also my comments above)

Answer (score 2):

See the suggestions given for [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4183/mathematical-physics-particularly-computational).

Also, for functional analysis, consider volume 1 of the 4-volume series [**Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125850506) by Reed/Simon, and keep [Kreyszig's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504599) handy for when you don't understand something -- note that Kreyszig's book has applications to quantum mechanics at the end.

Finally, for an nice overview of most areas of modern mathematics by a physicist, see Paul Roman's 2-volume **Some Modern Mathematics for Physicists and Other Outsiders: An Introduction to Algebra, Topology, and Functional Analysis** (Volume 1 [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1483171566) with views to table of contents of both volumes, an amazon review of both volumes [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0080181333)).