# Book recommendation for beginner

Tags: book-recommendation, advice

I understand this question seems to be off-topic and basic to you. But I want to learn about mathematics, I understand that it depends on many factors, but what I really wanted was the recommendation of some books that could help me — *a computer science student*. Maybe books like logic, statistics, sets, or any other field you think is important.

That's the point of the question. However, if you can recommend me a book like "how to solve problems", I would appreciate it, because I don't just want to learn math as a device to become a better programmer, I want to learn about this discipline that, for me, is interesting.

Comment: How much math have you learned so far?

Comment: @littleO I don't know how to measure it. But I know a few things, arithmetic, sets, matrices, computation logic, there must be more, but it's all very simple. I'm a Computer Science student, I feel that learning math is very important.

Comment: Logic and asymptotics are relevant to CS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hardy and Wright

Comment: The background you described in a Comment should be added to the body of your Question.  I note that you said nothing about studying Calculus, so perhaps that should be added to your edit.  You will have to pick a direction of interest.  Then we can help with book recommendations.

Comment: In Which field you want to go like and what kind of math do you want to read even in beginner level like high school, Undergraduate??

Comment: With you being a computer science student it depends on what field of computer science you want to focus on. For example, my interest is in computer graphics so I study differential geometry, differential calculus, linear algebra, Euclidean geometry, etc. Here is a website that I thought was useful: https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~turk/math_gr_new.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I self-learn undergraduate math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127814/how-do-i-self-learn-undergraduate-math)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are in your junior year in College as a CS student. Mathematics is very broad, so you can't just want to learn "more math", it's more efficient to know exactly what you want to learn. I would recommend you focus on mastering linear algebra (check out "Linear Algebra with Applications" by Strang and "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler) and discrete mathematics (check out "Discrete mathematics and its applications" by Rosen) for now; after you take your mandatory calculus classes I would advise studying introductory analysis to learn how to write proofs (I recommend "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Bartle or "Real Analysis" by Rudin, if you have the time for a more challenging text"). So start with linear algebra and discrete math, that's the heart of everything for a CS major.

Answer (score 1):

If you know basic algebra, geometry and trigonometry as taught in schools typically up to age 16, then you could read "Pure Mathematics 1" by Backhouse or "Extending Mathematics 1" by Heard. These books correspond to what used to be called "Additional Mathematics" at Ordinary Level in England. They cover harder algebra, trigonometry and analytic geometry, as well as introducing calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good video on the subject by The Math Sorcerer on YouTube. He goes over different book titles, a little bit about what types of thing you can learn from them, and a little bit on why they are his recommendation.

Link here: https://youtu.be/pTnEG_WGd2Q